# Paginate custom post type in a specified pattern

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, custom-post-type

I have been struggling to develop a logic for custom pagination in Wordpress,

I have 3 post types, all of them have different number of records, let us say

CPT1 : 24 posts
CPT2 : 10 posts
CPT3 : 16 posts

I want to display 4 records each per page that means it would show 12 records as total on a single page,

The page pattern should be 
CPT1
CPT2
CPT3....

if any of the post type finishes the other two should compensate the records which is I am struggling with, below is the code that I have tried till now,

```
<?php 
$ContentType = array('Custom_post1', 'Custom_post2', 'Custom_post3');

global $post;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 0;
if($paged == 0 || $paged==1){
    $paged =1;
}

$postsPerPage = 4;
if($paged == 0 || $paged==1){
    $postOffset =0;
}else{
    $postOffset = (($paged-1) * $postsPerPage);
}

if(!empty($ContentType)){

    $CountingPosts = array(
        'post_type' => $ContentType,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 499,
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'tax_query' => $condition,
    );

    $Counts = get_posts( $CountingPosts );

    foreach ($ContentType as $Type){

        if($Type=='Custom_post1'){

            $orderby = 'date';
            $order    = 'DESC';

            $Post_args = array(
                'post_type' => $Type,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'offset'          => $postOffset,
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'tax_query' => $condition,
                'orderby'          => $orderby,
                'order'            => $order,
            );

            $array['Custom_post1'] = get_posts( $Post_args );
        }


        if($Type=='Custom_post2'){
            $orderby = 'meta_value';
            $order    = 'DESC';

            $CPT_arg = array(
                'post_type' => $Type,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                'offset'          => ($postOffset),
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'tax_query' => $condition,
                'meta_key'  =>  'relevance_score',
                'orderby'          => $orderby,
                'order'            => $order,
            );
            $array['Custom_post2'] = get_posts( $CPT_arg );

        }

         if($Type=='Custom_post3'){
            $orderby = 'meta_value';
            $order    = 'DESC';

            $CPT_arg = array(
                'post_type' => $Type,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage,
                'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
                'offset'          => ($postOffset),
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'tax_query' => $condition,
                'meta_key'  =>  'relevance_score',
                'orderby'          => $orderby,
                'order'            => $order,
            );
            $array['Custom_post3'] = get_posts( $CPT_arg );

        }
       wp_reset_query();
       $count++;
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) { 

    if(!empty($array['Custom_post1'][$i])){
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($array['Custom_post1'][$i]->ID,'thumbnail');
        $alt_text = get_post_meta( $thumbnail->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
        $relevance_score = floor(get_field('relevance_score', $array['Custom_post1'][$i]->ID));
        toGetPostsOfTags($array['Custom_post1'][$i]->ID, 'Custom_post1', $relevance_score);
    }

    if(!empty($array['Custom_post2'][$i])){
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($array['Custom_post2'][$i]->ID,'thumbnail');
        $alt_text = get_post_meta( $thumbnail->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
        $relevance_score = floor(get_field('relevance_score', $array['Custom_post2'][$i]->ID));
        toGetPostsOfTags($array['Custom_post2'][$i]->ID, 'Custom_post2', $relevance_score);
    }

    if(!empty($array['Custom_post3'][$i])){
        $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($array['Custom_post3'][$i]->ID,'thumbnail');
        $alt_text = get_post_meta( $thumbnail->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
        toGetPostsOfTags($array['Custom_post3'][$i]->ID, 'post');
    }
}
?>
```